# Collect NGINX access.log statistics to Prometheus

Tags: nginx, logging, prometheus

There is nginx web server, that serves API calls from different User-Agents. I want to parse nginx logs and collect statistics about API calls from different User-Agents.

I'm going to write python script to parse nginx `access.log` like this https://gist.github.com/sysdig-blog/22ef4c07714b1a34fe20dac11a80c4e2#file-prometheus-metrics-python-py

Is there more suitable solution?

Comment: Take a look into google's mtail

Answer (score 0):

I highly discourage this approach.

Parsing logs is an old task, and there are many tools out there that are more than capable of doing this in an efficient way.

For me personally, I had success with [Fluentd - Open Source Data Collector](https://www.fluentd.org/), but there are more tools, depending on your specific needs.

The community, e.g, the amount, and quality of plugins/addons to the tool, is relevant when choosing the tool.

So if googling [fluentd prometheus](https://www.google.com/search?q=fluntd+prometheus) gets you some results from github and the developer itself - that might be your right course of action.

Answer (score 0):

When an application doesn't expose whitebox monitoring endpoints, parsing the logs is the only solution.

From there, you have multiple choices depending on the scale and the budget of your setup:

- centralizing logs (in ES by example) using a sidecar like Filebeat to parse and ship them. You can then make queries  to export statistics
- log parsing that expose statistics: fluentd, telegraf, mtail are good examples
- regular executions of a script that dump the data in a prom file to be collected by a node exporter is also a cheap solution

Rolling your own script would be a last resort: if you need statistics you cannot get from of the shelve tools or statistics that need context to be extracted. But it comes at the cost of handling painful scenarios; in your case, following the file when it rolls can be an issue.